# Guzzle Error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am following with the article below, 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

But in the end, when I try with the sample code (HelloAnalytics.php), it will shows the error in command line as follows and cant get the data;

> PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
>       PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Project 687417168367 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Google Analytics API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367"}],"code":403,"message":"Project 687417168367 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Google Analytics API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}} in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\s in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Project 687417168367 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Google Analytics API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367"}],"code":403,"message":"Project 687417168367 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Google Analytics API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=687417168367 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}} in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\s in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

Can somebody assist me?
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

As stated here  [count(): Parameter must be an array or an object](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1377)

> Please try upgrading your version of Guzzle.
>
> The problem is in PHP 7.2 the parameter for count() can't be NULL. The warning in the first post gets displayed when $this->handles equals NULL. Just replace line 67 in CurlFactory.php with the following:
>
> if (($this->handles ? count($this->handles) : 0) >= $this->maxHandles) {

Answer (score 6):

Some people could meet this issue (in a local environment) when upgrading to Mac OS Catalina. This, upgraded my php version from 7.1 to 7.3, so I had the same issue with CurlFactory (used version 6.2.1 of Guzzle).

This can be fixed by updating your version of Guzzle to 6.3.0 (minimal).
**How to do this** :

```
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.0"
}
```

Then in a terminal (in the root of your project) :

```
composer update
```

**OR, if you can't change your Guzzle version (for a reason or another.. This is my case)**

- You can instead, change your version of php by installing 7.1 (with homebrew in my sample. If you don't have it you can find/install here : https://brew.sh/index)

Then in a terminal type :

```
brew update
brew install php@7.1
```

In some case, you'll have to link to php 7.1 with the following command :

```
brew link php@7.1
```

Finally, re-launch your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I have fixed it by updating the `Guzzle` via composer. 
First add this in your composer

```
 "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3.1"
}
```

Then write

```
composer update
```

in your command prompt

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue wasn't critical, after trying the solutions above I got to the conclusion I just needed to remove the errors and everything worked.

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2.0', '>=')) {
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
}
```

This code is only required on localhost, the production server doesn't output warnings anyway.

Answer (score 2):

php composer.phar update guzzlehttp/guzzle