# count() method needs an array as parameter regarding "$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);"

Tags: php, xampp, google-oauth, guzzle

I am trying to integrate google login on my website. I have added compose and installed google auth version 2.0.

code for **config.php**

```
<?php

//start session on web page
session_start();

//config.php

//Include Google Client Library for PHP autoload file
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Make object of Google API Client for call Google API
$google_client = new Google_Client();

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client ID
$google_client->setClientId('XXXXXX');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client Secret key
$google_client->setClientSecret('XXXXXX');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URI
$google_client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/MMCOE_LINER/basic_login/login.php');

// to get the email and profile 
$google_client->addScope('email');

$google_client->addScope('profile');

?>
```

code for **index.php**

```
<?php


//Include Configuration File
include('config.php');

$login_button = '';


if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{

    $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);


 if(!isset($token['error']))
 {
 
  $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

 
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];


  $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);

 
  $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
  echo $data;

 
  if(!empty($data['given_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['family_name']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['email']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['gender']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_gender'] = $data['gender'];
  }

  if(!empty($data['picture']))
  {
   $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
  }
 }
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{

 $login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'">Login With Google</a>';
}

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PHP Login using Google Account</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">PHP Login using Google Account</h2>
   <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <?php
   if($login_button == '')
   {
    echo '<div class="panel-heading">Welcome User</div><div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION["user_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail" />';
    echo '<h3><b>Name :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].' '.$_SESSION['user_last_name'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><b>Email :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_email_address'].'</h3>';
    echo '<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</h3></div>';
   }
   else
   {
    echo '<div align="center">'.$login_button . '</div>';
   }
   ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am running it on Xampp

**So, after running index.php and selecting my Gmail account I am getting an error, the complete error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:67 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(67): count(NULL) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(107): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->release(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle)) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(72): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(30): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php(68): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(57): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(268): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(104): GuzzleHttp\Client->sendAsync(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\google\auth\src\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php(34): GuzzleHttp\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) 
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(492): Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) 
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(184): Google\Auth\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken(Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler)) 
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\login.php(15): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('4/0ARtbsJrk6JH4...') 
#17 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcoe_liner\basic_login\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
```

**Also, after some debugging I found out the error is here :**

```
$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);
```

Comment: Please update your composer packages especially [Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898330/guzzle-error-count-parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-co).

Comment: vee, how do i exactly fo that, I was searching for a way to do so. I ran composer update in the folder but do I need to change the version of guzzlehttp/guzzle and how?

Comment: From the link I gave to you they said _This can be fixed by updating your version of Guzzle to 6.3.0 (minimal)_. And from [Guzzle GitHub page](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), it's depend on your PHP version. If you use PHP >= 7.2.5 then you can upgrade to newest (7.x) version but you may need to update your code if they have something breaks. Please read more on the link from my first comment.

Comment: Or you may have to update Google client instead if your composer.json doesn't have Guzzle, it means Guzzle is required by Google client alone and Google client may required specific version of Guzzle. Try to upgrade Google client before.

Comment: looks like updating the google api client to latest version worked

Comment: drop the user info end point its not going to always return the data you are trying to get.   Use the people api get method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
```

You appear to be under the assumption that the userinfo endpoint returns information like gender and name. Which it does not.  You cant even guarantee that it will return email and name sometimes.

Try doing a print on the data var to see what is actually being returned

```
print_r($data);
```

That is why we use the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method as you have already requested profile scope you should have access to it.